# How can I use "spline" or Interpolation on a UK Map?

Tags: interpolation, mapping, matlab, spline

Basically, I have a number of data across a number of UK cities (London, Aberdeen, Birmingham, etc.). I want to plot them onto a map and then use something like a "contour map" to get something similar to this.

[image]

I have been trying to figure that out using MATLAB, Origin, python, etc. but I am lost. I am thinking about using an ordinary map and plotting the data to the corresponding cities. Then, using spline or interpolation of some sort. Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you would like to plot your point data like a spatially continuous map. To do this, firstly you need coordinates (latitude and longitude) of the cities, and then you can use QGIS (freely available) to do spatial interpolation. There are different methods used for spatial interpolation. This QGIS tutorial explains them very well.

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/interpolating_point_data.html